# Converting IP addresses from long int format to string

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, ip, long-integer

I am working in Python with data that contains IPv4 addresses. These IP addresses are under long int format - which I didn't know was a way to store them. I need to have them as string format, such as 10.10.10.10.
I have no documentation on this format, I only know it can be converted.

The only decoder I found is an online website that does the correct conversion (https://cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/long2ip).

I'd like to be able to run this kind of code:

```
In [0]: long2ip(-9223090565996790175)
Out[0]: '10.129.62.97'
```

Does anyone know how to do the conversion in Python? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it with tools in the standard lib

```
import socket, struct

def convert_long(longip):
    socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', longip))
```

Comment: This only works for positive long integers, I believe. I forgot to mention that the long ints in my data are negative, such as the example in my post.
When I try your proposition, I get 'argument out of range'.

Comment: @gaelchls I don't know of any spec for negative long IPs. The range is usually 0 - 4294967295. If that one online tool works for you, that's a fluke/bug. Perhaps you're misinterpreting some binary representation of a long into a negative number.